# C++ pointer copy overloading

Tags: c++, overloading

I want to overload the pointer copy like below code. 
I tried many things, but I didn't find the way...

```
template <typename T>
Class Test {
private:
    T* obj;
public:
    inline Test<T>& operator= (const Test<T>& other) {
    }
    inline Test<T>* operator= (const Test<T>* other) {
    }
    inline Test<T> operator= (const Test<T> other) {
    }
    ...
}
int main() {
    Test *a, *b;
    a = new Test;

    // *b = *a; // I know how to overload this copy
    b = a;   // But, I want to overload this pointer copy operator!
}
```

Comment: In this case I'd make a clone method to make the intention clear. Otherwise I'd expect there is only one raw pointer that should be deleted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But, I want to overload this pointer copy operator!

You cannot. Pointer assignment will always employ the built-in operation. You cannot overload any operator for built-in types - that includes pointers, even *if* they point to a class type - the built-in assignment will always be used instead.